# Changing Link Color Property with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to change the font color of a link on my HTML page. While the rest of the JavaScript works fine, the link refuses to change color.

Initially, the link font color is white:

```
a {
    color: white;   
}
```

However, when a button is clicked, this function is performed:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.a.style.color = "black";
}
```

There must be another way to define 'a' in the JavaScript, but google hasn't helped. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend looking in to [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the link first before you can modify it.

There are a couple ways to select elements in JavaScript. The most common are:

[`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) if you want to select a single element by its HTML `id` attribute

[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) if you want to select the first or all elements matching a CSS selector

[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) if you want to select elements based on their `class` attribute

Additionally, you can select all links in a document via [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links)

Answer (score 0):

this line: `document.a.style.color = "black";` just tries to access an undefined member `a` in the `document` object. You'd have to select the desired `a`(the anchor element on your page) element, then apply the color modification.

There are several ways to do the "selection process" of the `a` element:

- You can use the built-in [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method if you already gave the `a` element an `ID`: i.e giving an `ID` of 'anchor-element' to the `a` element: `var anchor = document.getElementById('anchor-element`);`.
- Another option is to use the built-in [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method if you already gave the `a` element a `class`: i.e giving an `class` of 'anchor-element' to the `a` element, and let's say the it's the only element to have that class: `var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName('anchor-element`)[0];`.
- There are other options such as [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).

Here's a demo, we'll be using `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` to change some links color on a button click:

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn-1'),
    btn2 = document.getElementById('btn-2');

btn1.addEventListener('click', handler);
btn2.addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler(e) {
  if(e.target === btn1) {
    // selecting the 'a' element using 'getElementById'.
    var a = document.getElementById('some-id');
    a.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    // selecting the 'a' element using 'getElementsByClassName'.
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class')[0];
    a.style.color = 'green';
  }
}
```

```css
/* just for this demo */
a, button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="some-id">getElementById is used</a>
<button id="btn-1">Change 1<sup>st</sup> link's color</button>
<a href="#" class="some-class">getElementsByClassName is used</a>
<button id="btn-2">Change 2<sup>nd</sup> link's color</button>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it work

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        a {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#">link text</a>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button> 

</body>
<script>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color = "black";
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. Remember to use `window.onload` to make sure an element is loaded before you attach an `onclick` event to it. Here is one of the ways.

```js
window.onload = function() {

    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.color = 'black';
        }
    }
    
    // Change all links
    document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function () {
        myFunction();
    }

    // Change one link
    document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function () {
         document.getElementById('onelink').style.color = 'blue';
    }
}
```

```css
body { background-color: #999999; }
a { color: white; }
#button1, #button2 { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a><br><br>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com" id="onelink">YouTube</a><br><br>  
<input type="submit" id="button1" value="Change all links to black"><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="button2" value="Change one link to blue">
```